# How can I add text in the top right corner of a page _without_ using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, positioning, margins, overlays

I want to put a block of text into the top right corner of my document (which uses the article class). The specifications of the document's formatting are **very** detailed, and it has taken me about 2 days to get them right.

I do not want to put a line across the top, or to do anything which will change the margin. In fact, I would prefer to avoid using any additional packages at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package or the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package could be an option. Why don't you want to use additional package(s)?

Comment: Yes, many pages add functionality without modifying the document layout/margins. Another one that can be used to place document elements anywhere on the page is [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). And, I'm pretty sure both [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) and [`tikz/pkg`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) will be able to accommodate this.

Comment: The packages I've already tried (e.g. scrpage2) produce strange _additional_ changes, which are sometimes hard to notice at first. For example, scrpage2 insists on a flexible page size, and cuts off the page numbers as a side effect of adding the header if I try to use fixed margins (which are required)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [`atbegshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) guarantees that the text block will not be modified in any way, as it acts by "overlaying", so to speak.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax,-1.5cm){\makebox[0pt][r]{\framebox{Copyright DTV}}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Every page of the document will bear the copyright notice.

Comment: How can I make this appear only on the front page?

Comment: @roland Use `\AtBeginShipoutFirst`

Comment: @egreg i tried that but it didn't work. It just removes the first page.

Comment: @roland `\AtBeginShipoutNext`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple example using the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\SetBgContents{some additional text}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgPosition{current page.north east}
\SetBgHshift{-2cm}
\SetBgVshift{-1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a minimal example using the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\paperwidth}%
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{Here is some interesting text}
}}}%

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

`\AddToShipoutPictureBG` will print something on *every* page, while the starred version `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` prints it on the current page only. Placement is possible with spacing commands, with the help of predefined locations (like `\AtPageUpperLeft` and the like). See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/eso-pic.pdf) for more on this.

`eso-pic` also provides placement of contents in the foreground to overlay with the existing page layout (in contrast to placing something in the background layer as suggested above) using `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` or `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` with similar connotations as above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `textpos`, the process is automatized so that the text will **always** stay at top right corner even when page geometry is changed

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a4paper, twoside]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1.0 pt}
\textblockorigin{\paperwidth}{0.0 pt}
%% set the origin used by 'textpos' to be top right corner of page

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\date{\today}
\author{author}

\pgfmathwidth{"top right corner at page \thepage"}
%% the width of text is stored in '\pgfmathresult'
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[1, 0](0, 0)
%% value of '\pgfmathresult' is used to set the width of text block
%% '[1, 0]' sets the anchor point of text block to be its top right corner
%% '(0, 0)' sets the anchor point right at the origin which is set by '\textblockorigin' in the preamble
\noindent
top right corner at page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\maketitle

\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

here is what is produced

[image: top right corner text]