# How to place an image in bottom left hand corner on every page?

Tags: preamble

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx)

I would like to place a small image in the bottom left hand corner of every page of my document.  The image is in .jpg format.  The snag is that I am not allowed to install extra packages to latex at work.

Can I do this by redefining a new page style, and writing the commands to do this in the preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What document class are you using?

Comment: See [How can I add text in the top right corner of a page _without_ using `fancyhdr`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30177/5764); [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and `graphicx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38751/5764). Without more knowledge of the packages that you cannot install or don't have access to, one of these could be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with eso pic

I think this code should work, put it in the preamble

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\EveryShipout{
\AddToShipoutPicture*{
     \put(0,0){\includegraphics{image.png}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works.  I was using the book class. Phil,