# Image at bottom right Corner of the type area

Tags: graphics, positioning, backgrounds

With the following code I put an image in the bottom left corner of a page (see [How to place an image in bottom left hand corner on every page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88545/how-to-place-an-image-in-bottom-left-hand-corner-on-every-page) too).

```
\newcommand{\BackgroundPic}
{%
\put(0,0){%
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,%
keepaspectratio]{images/test.png}%
}}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
```

But I want to put the image to the *bottom right corner of the type area*. How can I do this? I need the coordinates of the bottom right corner of the type area (without TikZ) …

Comment: -1 for `without TikZ` ;-) Joking.

Comment: Haha :D Is it possible with TikZ?

Comment: I prefer a more „native“ solution, but will accept TikZ if no native solution exists (which I don’t believe).

Comment: I was joking again. There is a `tikz` solution that may get updated within an hour. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe,marginparsep=0pt,marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}}}
\begin{document}
 Some text here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: RTFM :D Thank you! It does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

A `tikz` solution any way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[anchor=south east,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south east) +(-1in,1in)$) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes:

I have added the picture in the background and picture is added only for one page. If you want the picture for all / some pages, use `background` package. If you change the margin, use appropriate values in `($(current page.south east) +(-1in,1in)$)`. `(-1in,1in)` is actually `(<-right margin>,<bottom margin>)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not fully answer my question. First, I can put coordinates at `\put(x,y)` too, so no TikZ is necessary, right? Second, my type area is automatically calculated with KOMA Script. So I have to obtain the coordinates and do not set constants.

Comment: I think we have to use something like `\evensidemargin`, `\oddsidemargin`, `\textheight` and `\textwidth` …