# Background-image on titlepage at upper right corner

Tags: graphics, eso-pic

I am trying to add a background image at the upper right corner of my titlepage with 1cm margins to the top and the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\providecommand*\LenToUnit[1]{#1\@gobble}

\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{
\put(\LenToUnit{0.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
 \AtPageUpperRight{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{logo.pdf}}}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to right align the image?

Comment: Related -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147217/34618 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38751/34618

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
   \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperRight{\raisebox{-\height}{\frame{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Uni-Logo}}}}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it only works with demo options. "LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in logo.pdf (no BoundingBox)." How can i set margins to the right and top?

Comment: did you run `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes, i used pdflatex.

Comment: Then your image is buggy. Can you provide it for a download?

Comment: I do not open exe files ...

Comment: When downloading I get Uni-Logo.pdf.exe

Comment: http://molecule-pp.de/Uni-Logo.pdf

Comment: no problem. See image in edited answer. I suppose that you have a `dvips` option or something else in your definitions.

Comment: what if I want the logo to be a little bit more to the left? not in the corner

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Uni-Logo}\qquad`  or something similiar.

Answer (score 15):

Piece of cake with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I put the picture in the bottom right corner? I tried to replace ``north`` with ``south`` and ``east`` with ``west`` but that won't work :(

Comment: @Coxa `anchor=south east` and `at (current page.south east)`. i.e., `\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}};`