# How to apply header to every page after title page

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to add my name to the top right corner of every page but the title page. I have been using the solutions in the link below for reference as I have similar requirements for how to create the header, but all of the methods apply the header to the title page also. How can I apply the header to every page but the title page?

Link I have been referencing:

[How can I add text in the top right corner of a page _without_ using fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30177/how-can-i-add-text-in-the-top-right-corner-of-a-page-without-using-fancyhdr)

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are many incomplete informations like which document class you are using, are you using `titlepage` or `\maketitle` etc. Please clarify and post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adopt the answers given in the link like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Some article}
\author{Author here}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\afterpage{\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax,-1.5cm){\makebox[0pt][r]{\framebox{Copyright DTV}}}%
}}}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

With `background` package, you can use `\NoBgThispage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=.9,
  position=current page.north east,
  nodeanchor=north east,
  hshift=-2cm,
  vshift=-1cm,
  firstpage=true,
  contents={Some text}
  }

\title{Some article}
\author{Author here}

\begin{document}
\NoBgThispage
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

And this is Werner's solution adopted for your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{afterpage}

\title{Some article}
\author{Author here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\afterpage{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\paperwidth}%
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{Here is some interesting text}
}}}%
}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I show the plain TeX solution here. You didn't specify what macro package are you using.

```
\def\nextheader#1{\headline={\hfil\global\headline={#1}}}

%%% usage:

\nextheader{My Name\hfil}

Title of the document
\vfil\break

Normal text
\bye
```