# How to draw a (colored) square at the (upper right) corner of the page?

Tags: color, rules, draw, box

I think I could draw a square with the \rule command, but I can’t place it at the corner of the page. How can I change the absolute position of my square?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer now:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \hspace{\paperwidth}%
      \raisebox{-\height}{%
         \makebox[0pt][r]{{\color{red}\rule{40pt}{40pt}}}
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks to [@werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30185/115738)